# How to rotate an image around a point in Java

Tags: java, image-rotation

I have been looking at some similar questions but none answer exactly what I need. In the solutions I found, everyone rotated the image without moving, but what I need is for this image to rotate around the initial position, and not for it to rotate in position.

Code I was using (what I found):

```
        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), img.getWidth() / 2, img.getHeight() / 2);
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
        img = op.filter(img, null);

        g.drawImage(img, getX(), getY(), null);
```

I need the image to rotate in relation to the first pixel of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rotate` method you’re calling passes in the anchor point as the center of the image:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#rotate(double,%20double,%20double)

Try just passing in the rotation angle itself and it should rotate around the top-left:

```
transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));
```

Comment: bruh... That was easy. Thanks so much!